# Ethernet not working Ubuntu server 22.04

Tags: networking, drivers, server, ethernet

I just upgraded to a new motherboard, cpu, and memory. This came with a new Ethernet controller, and now my Ethernet is not working. It’s not giving me an up address. The lights were off on the Ethernet port until I ran `ip link set enp7s0 up` is there a fix? My old Ethernet controller was Realtek so I already have the drivers installed. Kernel 5.15.0-58 generic

Comment: And what is the new adapter?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.